# Problems installing artifactory service on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (HVM) Amazon AWS image

Tags: artifactory

I'm getting this, which doesn't help me a lot. Tomcat logs are not yet created, and the war files not yet expanded, so I guess tomcat cannot even start. How can I figure out the problem?

```
systemctl status artifactory.service                                                                 
● artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-02-05 22:25:30 CET; 1s ago
  Process: 13760 ExecStart=/0/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I followed these [installation instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-InstallingArtifactory.1), downloaded and extracted JFrog Artifactory OSS 5.8.3, then

```
unzip /0/artifactory.zip -d /0
mv /0/artifactory-oss-5.8.3 /0/artifactory
chmod +x /0/artifactory/bin/*
ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/0/artifactory bash -c '/0/artifactory/bin/installService.sh'
```

Then edited /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Default values
export ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/0/artifactory
export ARTIFACTORY_USER=artifactory
export JAVA_HOME=/a/java/jdk1.8_lin64

export TOMCAT_HOME=/0/artifactory/tomcat
export ARTIFACTORY_PID=$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/run/artifactory.pid

export JAVA_OPTIONS="-server -Xms512m -Xmx756m -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\""
export JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dartdist=zip -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

# Timeout waiting for artifactory to start
# START_TMO=60
```

Finally reinstalled service (do I have to uninstall somehow first?)

```
ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/0/artifactory bash -c '/0/artifactory/bin/installService.sh'
systemctl start artifactory.service || true
systemctl status artifactory.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a permissions problem.

Eventually I unzipped to `/opt/artifactory` (instead of `/0/artifactory`), and things started to work.

I found the problem by trying to manually start artifactory.

I looked inside `/opt/artifactory/misc/service/artifactory.service` and found:

```
ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start
```

Inside `artifactoryManage.sh` I looked at the `start` method and found:

```
su -s "/bin/sh" ${ARTIFACTORY_USER} -c "export JAVA_HOME='$JAVA_HOME'; $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
```

I manually resolved the variables by changing this to:

```
su -s "/bin/sh" artifactory -c "export JAVA_HOME=/a/java/jdk1.8_lin64; /opt/artifactory/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"
```

And then received the permission error. I vaguely remembered reading something about permissions in the installation instructions:

[image]